# How to use a boolean to rename and replace values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe, and a few data columns have missing catagories represented by a `'?'` in a column. I am trying to use a boolean to rename and replace the missing catagories marked `'?'` with `'Private'`in a column labled `workclass`. The data is read in as:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import *
url2="https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data" #Reading in Data from a freely and easily available source on the internet
Adult = pd.read_csv(url2, header=None)
##Assigning column names to the dataframe
Adult.columns = ["age","workclass","fnlwgt","education","educationnum","maritalstatus","occupation",  
                 "relationship","race","sex","capitalgain","capitalloss","hoursperweek","nativecountry",
                 "less50kmoreeq50kn"]
```

I have tried running the code:

```
MissingValue = Adult.loc[:, "workclass"] == "?"
Adult.loc[MissingValue, "workclass"] = "Private"
```

and

```
Adult.loc[ Adult.loc[:, "workclass"] == "?", "workclass"] = "Private"
```

I do not get any error's when running the code however when checking the column values with `(Adult.loc[:,'workclass'].value_counts())` the `'?'` is still there.
The code: `Adult['workclass'] = Adult['workclass'].str.replace('?', 'Private')` works for what I want to accomplish however I would like to be able to do it with a boolean. Any suggestions on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are spaces after delimiter, so add `skipinitialspace` parameter:

```
Adult = pd.read_csv(url2, header=None, skipinitialspace=True)
```

And then working correctly your code:

```
MissingValue = Adult["workclass"] == "?"
Adult.loc[MissingValue, "workclass"] = "Private"

print ((Adult['workclass'].value_counts().index.tolist()))
['Private', 'Self-emp-not-inc', 'Local-gov', 'State-gov', 
 'Self-emp-inc', 'Federal-gov', 'Without-pay', 'Never-worked']

print ((Adult['workclass'].value_counts()))
Private             24532
Self-emp-not-inc     2541
Local-gov            2093
State-gov            1298
Self-emp-inc         1116
Federal-gov           960
Without-pay            14
Never-worked            7
Name: workclass, dtype: int64
```

Verify space with your code:

```
Adult = pd.read_csv(url2, header=None)

#Assigning column names to the dataframe
Adult.columns = ["age","workclass","fnlwgt","education","educationnum","maritalstatus","occupation",  
                 "relationship","race","sex","capitalgain","capitalloss","hoursperweek","nativecountry",
                 "less50kmoreeq50kn"]

print ((Adult['workclass'].value_counts().index.tolist()))
[' Private', ' Self-emp-not-inc', ' Local-gov', ' ?', ' State-gov',
 ' Self-emp-inc', ' Federal-gov', ' Without-pay', ' Never-worked']
```

Comment: @GregSullivan - I really recommended remove spces in read_csv, `str.strip` is possible use if problem only one specific column. Also if this spaces with numeric columns are parsed incorrectly without `skipinitialspace=True`.

Comment: Thank you, is there a time where skipinitialspace=True would cause errors? and how did you know the spaces were present? I am assuming this is a common problem.

Comment: @GregSullivan - `is there a time where skipinitialspace=True would cause errors?` I think it cannot cause errors.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is your value is does not match exactly `'?'` but is probably something like '?   '

You can see this because:

```
 Adult.loc[Adult['workclass']=='?',:]
```

returns an empty dataframe whereas

```
 Adult.loc[Adult['workclass'].str.strip()=='?',:]
```

returns 1836 rows

`strip` removes leading and trailing whitespaces so you don't have to test `' ?'`, `'? '`, `' ? '` etc

So when you slightly change your code like this

```
MissingValue = Adult.loc[:, "workclass"].str.strip() == "?"
Adult.loc[MissingValue, "workclass"] = "Private"
```

You will see that the '?' has disappeared from the `value_counts()`

Comment: Thank you! is there a difference between .str.strip() and reading in the data with skipinitiallinespace=True as mentioned below?

Comment: `skipinitiallinespace=True` is great in your case because you have the space in all columns. `.str.strip()` is useful when you don't have this behaviour everywhere, or if you need to clean data after reading, and also removes trailing whitespaces